# Why can't I center my nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to create a drop down nav menu and it works fine, but I can not get it to center on my page.

I have tried using align="center" in the div "menu", but that did not work. I then tried aligning it using the css for the div and the lis and uls, but that also did not work.

Here is my code

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#menu li").hover(function () {
            $(this).children(":hidden").slideDown();

            }, function(){

            $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();

        });

    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">drop3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #26C7FF;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

#menu li li:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu ul, #menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #26C7FF;
    display: none;
}

#menu li li {
    float: none;
    padding: 2px;
}

#menu a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: At the moment it's just 100% of the width of the page, right?

Comment: @Alex that is correct

Comment: Neat, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use display:inline-block; instead of floating the li elements and then use text-align:center; for the container ul.

```
#menu > ul > li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a working example:
http://codepen.io/taneleero/pen/MwojLV

Comment: awesome, this does exactly what I want it to do, and it stays a bit responsive. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a container that has a `max-width` of whatever width you'd like your menu to be:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px; // Or whatever
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu {
  height: 30px;
  background: #26C7FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="menu"> 
</div>
```

Comment: this semi-solves the problem, it makes the nav shorter and therefore gets it more towards the center, but I want it to span the entire window. The display: inline answer below seemed to work for me, thank you for the response

Comment: @Ddrossi93 Gotcha - my understanding was that you wanted the entire nav bar in the centre of the window, not the content.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code. I think this is what you wanted.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu li").hover(function() {

      $(this).children(":hidden").slideDown();



    }, function() {

      $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();


    });



  }); < /script>
```

```css
#menu {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #26C7FF;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
#menu li li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu ul,
#menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#menu li {
  float: none;
  width: 120px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #26C7FF;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#menu li li {
  float: none;
  padding: 2px;
}
#menu a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">drop1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">drop2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">drop3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">drop1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">drop2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/ensd3mte/) link

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting your ordered list tags at a fixed width, the following css should fix your problem.

```
#menu ul {
  width: 369px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lffkhf7/1/).

Comment: Anything with a fixed width in 2015 is invalid in my opinion. This limits the number of element that the menu can hold plus is a headache for responsive web.